# Regex to find zero or more occurance of substrings of different patterns

Tags: java, c#, .net, regex

I want a regex that will return zero or more occurrences of matched substrings of different patterns.

**Different patterns to match**

1. `<sym>Any value</sym>`
2. `<sps>Any value</sps>`
3. `<sbs>Any value</sbs>`
4. Any string including spaces and special characters which are outside of the above 3 tags

Where "Any value" is any string including spaces and special characters.

**Test Cases**

1. `abcd<sps>2</sps><sbs>yy</sbs>efgh<sym>b</sym>`
2. `<sym>nu</sym>Hello World<sps>6&</sps><sbs>10</sbs>With Special Characters$#<sym>b</sym>`
3. `<sps>2</sps>Test<sbs>yy</sbs><sym>b</sym>End String`

**Results**

1.

> ```
> abcd
> <sps>2</sps>
> <sbs>yy</sbs>  
> efgh
> <sym>b</sym>
> ```

2. 

> ```
> <sym>nu</sym>  
> Hello World 
> <sps>6&</sps>  
> <sbs>10</sbs>
> With Special Characters$#
> <sym>b</sym>
> ```

3. 

> ```
> <sps>2</sps>
> Test
> <sbs>yy</sbs>
> <sym>b</sym>
> End String
> ```

I tried the following regex:

`(?([a-zA-Z0-9]+))<sym>[^.]*</sym>|<sps>[^.]*</sps>|<sbs>[^.]*</sbs>(?([a-zA-Z0-9]+))`

**Result against "Test Case 1":** Getting the following strings where I am not getting the strings outside the tags.

`<sps>2</sps> <sbs>yy</sbs> <sym>b</sym>`

**Result against "Test Case 2":** Getting the full input text.

`<sym>nu</sym>Hello World<sps>6&</sps><sbs>10</sbs>With Special Characters$#<sym>b</sym>`

Could you please help me in this context. Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Is the input XML?  `<sps>6&</sps>` is not legal XML, so I’m not entirely clear on the format.

Comment: Consider using a proper XML parser, see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/14868997 You could for example use XPath `sym/text()` and `sps/text()`

Comment: Java and C# are different languages. Please choose one and delete the other tag.

Comment: @VGR, The input is not XML. I created those tags and the tags can contain anything including alphanumeric/special characters.

Comment: @Charlieface, parsing the XML is not my target. I want all the tags including the start and end tags with contained data. E.g., From test case 2, I expect the following result (separated by comma)

<sym>nu</sym>,
<sps>6&</sps>,
<sbs>10</sbs>,
<sym>b</sym>

Along with that the strings which are outside of any tags. Again from test case 2: (separated by comma)

Hello World,
With Special Characters$#

Please let me know if I missed anything to explain.

Comment: @AdrianHHH, I assumed the same regex is compatible with both Java and C#. I need this to use in C#. Although After searching I learned that, Java has all of the C# regex syntaxes but vice versa is not always compatible. But I think in this case the regex might be the same for both languages. Please correct me if I am wrong in this case.

Comment: You just need to add a `<Root>` tag around the whole string. Eg https://dotnetfiddle.net/wAtz0Q

Comment: @Charlieface, it's a nice idea to go with XML parser. I reviewed the solution you shared. It's also taking the texts which are inside the tag. Just removing the text which are inside the tags will solve the problem. I am not sure how to remove the texts from the tags.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/32F65r There are also ways to read XML without having an XML root, you need to use `XmlSerializer` for that I think

Comment: If this is not XML, does your markup notation account for the possibility that the text content might actually contain the six characters `</sbs>`?

Comment: @VGR, there can be any number of characters but I will use one or two which can be alphanumeric/special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a proper XML parser for this. In C# you can use XElement. Thhis allows you to use Linq-to-XML to query it.

Since your XML doesn't have a root, we need to add one.

```cs
var myxml = @"abcd<sps>2</sps><sbs>yy</sbs>efgh<sym>b</sym>";

var doc = XElement.Parse("<Root>" + myxml + "</Root>");
var nodes = doc.Descendants()
            .Where(e => e.Name == "sps" || e.Name == "sbs")
            .Cast<XNode>()
            .Concat(doc.Nodes().OfType<XText>());
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n", nodes));
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JE5qmC)

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. Just tested with all three test cases and seems to fail for the 2nd test case because there is an ampersand (&) inside a tag. Is there anything that ignores those special characters or any other ways?

Comment: No, `&` is a special character in XML, and should be enoded `&amp;`. You can try fix up your data, but it depends what exactly you are trying to achieve with the final result. If you don't do `Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n", nodes.Select(n => n.Value)));` then it will still contain `&amp;` https://dotnetfiddle.net/q6nqZ9

Comment: It will work. I can update the data format. Thanks a lot for helping me out. I am accepting the answer. However, I know it's quite difficult to achieve using Regex but I was interested if that could be done.

Comment: Ideally you should have valid XML in the first place, so you must have a single root element, and preferably an `<?xml>` preamble

Comment: Right, if that's a pure XML string. But I tried to use it as a normal string.

Answer (score 0):

Alternation seems to do what you want.  You need a final lookahead to stop the zero occurrence case from overconsuming.

```
"<sym>.+?<\/sym>|<sps>.+?<\/sps>|<sbs>.+?<\/sbs>|.+?(?=<s(?:ym|ps|bs)>|$)"gm
```

[image]

You can also shorten it with a backreference:

```
"<(sym|sps|sbs)>.+?<\/\1>|.+?(?=<s(?:ym|ps|bs)>|$)"gm
```

In this case the alternation is shortened to just the tag value, and the closing tag can reuse it with the backreference `\1`.

Comment: Hi @Chris, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, with the regex you mentioned, I only can find two matches for test case 1: (results are separated by comma)

<sps>2</sps>,
<sbs>yy</sbs>

And still missing the other strings (Please have a look into the results 1).